# php connection with android project

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android development. I want to connect a php file to the android app.  My php code is

```
<?php    
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "invoice_db");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect";
    }

    $response["sucess"]=0;
    $invoiceid = $_POST['invc']; 
    $response = array();
    $sql = "SELECT sl_no from invoice_table where invoice_id='$invoiceid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(!empty($result)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $data = $row[0];
        $response["sucess"] = 1;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here 'invc' is get from httpRequest ,

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_user, "POST",  params);
```

And my JSONParser page contains,

```
if (method == "POST") {
    // request method is POST
    // defaultHttpClient
    System.out.println("Inside json parser POST condition");
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    System.out.println("Inside json parser POST condition" + params);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    Log.d("From httpentity", httpEntity.toString());  
    System.out.println("ppppppppppppphhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhppppppppppp");
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
}
```

Now I want to check , whether the parameters were passed to the php page or not. So I want to console/log cat the `$invoiceid`. How can it possible in Eclipse Ide?

Comment: Another thing you might change is `method == "POST"` to `method.equals("POST")`.

Comment: that's true, in Java you must compare strings by using `.equals(...)` method, since the `==`  operator compares instances (i.e. references)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a variable inside PHP code, you can do `echo $variable`. However please note that PHP code will be executed on a server and not on your android device. Moreover your PHP code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Any other possibility available for show the variable in eclipse console/log cat. I dont want to show in browser console

Comment: PHP is executed on a web server, it has nothing to do with Android, so you cannot print anything to the logcat. You can print to LogCat the **result** of the call, that is the string/Json/HTML/whatever is returned by your PHP code.

Comment: @Rose: If you access the URL to the PHP in a browser, only then will it show the result in the browser. If you run it through your application, then you will have to print it using `Log`. As already pointed out, by @user2340612, you must cast the result in a `String`, for example. The point here is, if you need to check the output / result, you will have to use `echo $something` in your PHP

Comment: Since it is a POST request you cannot simply access the web page, but you need to use cURL or something similar instead. The idea proposed by @IceMAN, however, is valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON encoding method in your php file to get a proper JSON response like this.

```
$response = array (
                'invoiceid' => $verify_code,    
            );
print json_encode($response);
```

which will return a JSON string to your app in a format like

```
{"invoiceid":"null"}
```

which you can decode and log it like this

```
InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isw);
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
String finalresult = buffer.toString();
 JSONObject myobject = new JSONObject(finalresult);
            String flag= myobject.getString("invoiceid");

log.e("mylog",flag)
```

so that it will be visible in your logcat file.